# I added a Windows feature and now I can't boot into Windows, how can I remove or disable the feature now?

Tags: command-line, windows-11, safe-mode, dism

I have a Minisforum HM80 mini PC (may be relevant) running Windows 11 that serves as an in-kitchen PC for simple tasks, from web browsing, to watching videos, and playing light games. I saw a tutorial that would allow me to install Windows Subsystem for Android to see if I could add Android apps to it and tried to follow the instructions. I'm fairly comfortable with WSL so I figured it'd be pretty easy to learn.

https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-run-android-apps-on-windows-11-3048569

One of the first steps was to add the **Virtual Machine Platform** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** Windows features. I did that and now I am unable to boot into Windows (not even in safe mode). It blue screens immediately with code **CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED** and not much more to go off of.

I figure the features I recently added were preventing it from loading up. Maybe my system can't support it and doesn't support the VM platform. I couldn't find any relevant settings in the BIOS so probably should remove or at least disable it so I could diagnose further.

How can I remove or disable it now?

System restores or startup repair couldn't fix the problem. Safe mode won't work. I am able to get to command prompt and try to run the commands to remove them:

```
> dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:HypervisorPlatform 
> dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform
```

But apparently the package servicing commands are not available or loaded up? I just get the error 87, "The disable-feature option is unknown." I guess in safe mode I can't run that immediately and need to load it possibly?

Comment: Try this command : `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

Comment: Thanks. I ran the command and I don't think anything has changed. Still blue screens immediately with the same error.

Comment: Which command mode are you getting into, the one from the boot media?

Comment: Through the recovery options. Not sure what to call this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEkdv.jpg

Comment: Try the option of Startup Repair. For more info see [this](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/use-startup-repair-in-windows-11.14660/).